# I cant do return inside of a .then

Tags: flutter

Well I want to return a true state when the username and password match but here's the code

```
dataBaseHelper.getUserList().then((value) => {
      for(User userOB in value){
        if(userName == userOB.username && password == userOB.password){
          return true
        }
      }
    });
```

I cannot return inside the .then((value) =>{

})
why?
I'm new to flutter BTW

Comment: What are you returning `true` to? How are you calling the code you provided?

Comment: yes 'true' just like a simple function.
Thank you for commenting out, the answer bellow fix the problem :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `async await` instead of `then()`

```
var value = await dataBaseHelper.getUserList();
for(User userOB in value){
  if(userName == userOB.username && password == userOB.password){
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help <3 really appreciate it!

Comment: And that works because the earlier "return" is returning from your .then, not from the subroutine that encloses it.